# Как лучше передавать информацию о текущем языке веб-приложения на сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-сервер, web-apps

Пока я начитал два варианта:

1. Через cookies (а что делать если пользователь запретил использовать куки?);
2. Через headers (Accept-Language). Отслеживать его на сервере и в зависимости от установленного языка, выдавать информацию.

Какой из них наиболее правильный. И какой наиболее предпочтительней использовать в GraphQL-сервере. Или может быть, есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: ещё самый простой - в урл добавить /en/

Comment: ну, в браузере как определить понятно! А как мне передавать запрос на сервер, и чтобы сервер понимал, на каком языке выдавать данные?

Comment: В урл запроса добавить /en/, в том числе и в запросы к апи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В клиентской части веб-приложения, можно использовать [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) - передавая его значение (или слайс из первых двух символов) с HTTP-запросом, например как часть URI эндпоинта.

```js
console.log(window.navigator.language); 
console.log(window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2));
```

Заголовок `Accept-Language` может содержать несколько предпочтительных языков - тогда как `navigator.language` возвращает только один язык (программы-юзерагента)... и очень вероятно, что это именно тот язык, который наиболее предпочтителен для клиента.

Передача идентификатора языка в запросе (вместо извлечения из заголовка на сервере) позволяет пользователям API более удобно переопределять этот параметр.

---

Ну а примерным аналогом `Accept-Language`, на стороне клиента является `navigator.languages` (с 's' на конце).

Comment: «[Accept-Language] может содержать несколько предпочтительных языков» — почему недостаток? Преимущество же: если на сервере предпочтительный язык отсутствует, можно взять второй предпочтительный по порядку.

Comment: @andreymal, верно, спасибо. Скорректировал формулировку ответа, изменив на более нейтральную.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю за ответы. А если пользователь захочет принудительно сменить язык сайта, как в этом случае быть. Просто подменять Accept-Language? И тогда сервер будет думать, что язык системы сменился?

Comment: @VadimPashaev, ну если веб-приложение будет отправлять идентификатор языка в запросе (о чем и написан ответ), то со сменой локализации нет никаких проблем: для новых пользователей берем язык из юзерагента, а для уже переключивших локализацию, где-то храним выбор языка (в `localStorage`, например). Я считаю что что ИД языка должен отправляться веб-приложением (т.е., что сервер должен отдавать тот контент, который клиент запрашивает **явно**... Если же запрос через API и клиент не указал язык, то возвращать данные на английском).

Comment: Ок, понял. Благодарю)